# how to freeze header row while exporting excel sheet in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
string attachment = "attachment; filename=Memberslist.xls";
Response.ClearContent();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
// Create a form to contain the grid
HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
completeGV.Parent.Controls.Add(frm);
frm.Attributes["runat"] = "server";
frm.Controls.Add(completeGV);
frm.RenderControl(htw);
Response.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.End();
```

I'm using the above code for exporting the excel sheet but i need to freeze the header row while exporting the excel sheet. please help me out... this is killing me...

Comment: I don't think you can do something like freeze the excel header using this code.

Comment: will u please provide me a alternate method for such requirement... or link that help me... Thanks